# How to change the filters position from Venia Storefront like the filters from the Magento front view?

Tags: magento2, graphql, venia

Good afternoon everybody,

I am kind of a rookie using magento and I need help with this:

This are the filters from Magento front View, this filters can change position changing the position attribute in the magento/admin page.

[image]

this are the filters in the Venia-storefront:

[image]

As you can see there are not in the same position.
So my question is, is there any way to connect what its happening to the position in the Magento front to affect the Venia-Storefront equally?

I have tried a couple of things, and according to my investigation, that position value is saving itself in the back but I can access to it in the venia-front because maybe the graphql is not allowing it....

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked with latest magento version

Comment: or else we needed to fix by our own